# remove a character from all strings in a list

Tags: python

I have the list:

```
mylist = ["8 - 9-", "7 - 6-", "4-"]
```

How would I remove the last "-" from each element in mylist?

so that the output is

```
mylist = ["8 - 9", "7 - 6", "4"]
```

edit: Originally I had a space before the "-" but that should not have been there. Apologies.

Comment: What's your expected output if the input is `mylist = ["8 - 9 -", "7 - 6", "4 -"]`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Removing character in list of strings](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8282553/removing-character-in-list-of-strings)

Comment: First Google result when searching this question's exact title.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`rstrip`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/stdtypes.html#str.rstrip) and a list comprehension will do the job:

```
mylist = [s.rstrip('-') for s in mylist]
```

Strictly speaking, this doesn't remove "the last '-' from each element", but rather removes any trailing dashes. But given your sample data, it does what you'd like.

For example:

```
>>> mylist = ["8 - 9-", "7 - 6-", "4-"]
>>> mylist = [s.rstrip('-') for s in mylist]
>>> print(mylist)
['8 - 9', '7 - 6', '4']
```

Comment: This will fail in case of `-4-  `

Comment: @vks Sure, but the sample input has no case where a `-` is followed by a space. I'm guessing that my answer is what the OP was *really* asking for -- otherwise, he's free to use a more complicated solution.

Comment: Your code should work for the case that I added above, and thanks.  However, I screwed up when asking my question because I should not have added a space after the "-".

Comment: @PiccolMan In that case, the code I posted still works.

Comment: @jme for some reason this isn't working for me.  Do I have to load a module? Also, I am using python 3.  I'll accept your answer since this is a problem on my end, and you were the first to provide help.  Thanks.

Comment: @PiccolMan When you say "this isn't working", what do you mean?

Comment: It does not do anything to my list,  I'll probably figure out the problem don't worry.

Comment: @PiccolMan Make sure you're reassigning the result of the list comprehension to `mylist`. I've added an example.

Comment: I found the error.  There is a random number of spaces after each string.  So for example, the first element would be something like " 8 - 9- insert spaces here                           ".  Is there a way to remove those spaces?  I'll try using a list compression for the spaces.

Comment: @PiccolMan Yep. Change `s.rstrip('-')` to `s.rstrip('- ')`. That will remove any amount of spaces and dashes from the string.

Answer (score 2):

Using `re` would be more suitable as it can handle cases where there are `spaces` after `-`.It would remove them as well.

```
import re
print [re.sub(r"\s*-\s*$","",i)  for i in ["8 - 9 -", "7 - 6 -", "4 -"]]
```

Output:`['8 - 9', '7 - 6', '4']`

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2556108/how-to-replace-the-last-occurence-of-an-expression-in-a-string) would be good as well.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 the problem with it is it will remove `-` from `-4` as well

Comment: I guess that may or may not be desired, as the question's sample input doesn't cover these cases.

Answer (score 2):

If you want a strict "remove the last dash in each string," you can do this:

```
>>> mylist = ["8 - 9 -", "7 - 6 -", "4 -", "4 - ", "4 - 4"]
>>> [''.join(item.rsplit('-', maxsplit=1)) for item in mylist]
['8 - 9 ', '7 - 6 ', '4 ', '4  ', '4  4']
```

Note how the last dash is removed even if there is a number after it.

Comment: OP has not specified but i guess this will turn `-4` to `4`.Anyways this would be the fastest of all :)

Comment: Sorry, I shouldn't have added a space before "-".  Is there a way to do it without a space?

Comment: @PiccolMan - It works exactly the same way regardless of other characters in the string.