# How to create a list of files without their extensions in python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

I got lost when trying to get a list of files but without their extension.
I am getting the a list of files in this specific directory using:

```
files = os.listdir("C:/Users/sp500/")
```

All files are with ".csv" extension which I would like to remove (I need the list of tickers only).

Using strip as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8282553/removing-character-in-list-of-strings) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/678236/how-to-get-the-filename-without-the-extension-from-a-path-in-python) (I am getting this error: TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not list) doesn't help nor other remove function etc.
I will appreciate your help very much!

Comment: You're not trying to rename them, are you?

Comment: no. not trying to rename. only remove extension