# removing the extension from list of files in a list in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

This is not a duplicate question!
I got lost when trying to get a list of files but without their extension.
I am getting the a list of files in this specific directory using:

```
files = os.listdir("C:/Users/sp500/")
```

All files are with ".csv" extension which I would like to remove (I need the list of tickers only).

Using strip as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8282553/removing-character-in-list-of-strings) and using

```
import os
print(os.path.splitext("path_to_file")[0])
```

as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/678236/how-to-get-the-filename-without-the-extension-from-a-path-in-python), I am getting this error:

> TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not list

doesn't help nor other remove function etc.

I will appreciate your help very much!

Comment: the accepted answer of the linked question is exactly the answer I posted, so it should work.

Comment: thanks for the link! solved after 2 days of searching!