# Change Character in Sublist

Tags: python, list

I already know this is a really dumb question. I tried looking up my answer but I barely know what to ask. (sorry if the title is a little vague). But Here I go. I have a list of words. I'm wanting to get rid of the bad characters in that list.

```
List = ["I?", "Can", "!Not", "Do.", "It"]
BadChars = ["?", "!", "."]

for word in List:
    for char in word:
        if char in BadChars:
            char = ""

print(List)
```

Again, I know this is very simple, but I just can't figure it out. Forgive me.

EDIT: Btw, it's not giving me an error. It's just returning the List untouched.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Removing character in list of strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8282553/removing-character-in-list-of-strings)

Comment: @davedwards I appreciate your comment. I already looked at this post about 20 minutes ago and it didn't help me.

Comment: you're almost there! Problem is that you set the variable `char` to `''` if it is in the `BadChars` list and leave the `word` unchanged. What you really want is setting the char in `word` to `''` if it is in `BadChars`, this can be done using the [`replace`](https://www.pythoncentral.io/pythons-string-replace-method-replacing-python-strings/) method, like `word.replace("?", "")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the `replace` method, for each char for each word:

```
List = ["I?", "Can", "!Not", "Do.", "It"]
BadChars = ["?", "!", "."]

for i in range(len(List)):
  for char in BadChars:
    List[i] = List[i].replace(char, "")

print(List) # ==> ['I', 'Can', 'Not', 'Do', 'It']
```

A regex may be used as well:

```
import re

List = ["I?", "Can", "!Not", "Do.", "It"]
BadChars = ["?", "!", "."]
rgx = '[%s]'%(''.join(BadChars))

List = [re.sub(rgx, "", word) for word in List]

print(List) # ==> ['I', 'Can', 'Not', 'Do', 'It']
```

Comment: This worked! Thank you so much. I really do appreciate it.

Comment: Glad it helped.

Comment: @davedwards Yeah I already upvoted and i'm going to Accept this answer when the cool down is off.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a generator expression that iterates over each character in a string and retains characters that are not in `BadChars`:

```
[''.join(c for c in s if c not in BadChars) for s in List]
```

This returns:

```
['I', 'Can', 'Not', 'Do', 'It']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
List = ["I?", "Can", "!Not", "Do.", "It"]
l=[]
BadChars = ["?", "!", "."]
for i in List:
    for j in BadChars:
        if j in i:
            i=i.strip(j)
    l.append(i)


print(l)
```

Just use strip method to remove BadChars from List