# How to store string with tabs in a list in python

Tags: python, list, data-structures, tabs

Looks like im missing something very simple here. I have list of elements in this format now few elements in the list have '\t' (tab or multiple tabs). Now instead of '\t' i want to store them as tab in the list. I iterating over each element and doing .replace('\t', '  ') clearly this isnt working.

l = ['test', '\tabc', '\t\tcde']

I want this to be stored as

l = ['test', 'abc', 'cde'] #It isnt allowing to add whitespaces I am looking to add is 2 space or 4 space indent based on number of \t infront of an element.

Can someone please help?

Comment: They **are strored as tabs in the list**. A `\t` in the `repr` of a `str` stands for a tab.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Removing character in list of strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8282553/removing-character-in-list-of-strings)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my attempt:

```
l = ['test', '\tabc', '\t\tcde']
l = list(map(lambda elem: elem.replace('\t', ' '), l))

print(l)
```

Output:

```
['test', ' abc', '  cde']
```