# How do I get a normal list with strings instead of generator objects when I perform a googlesearch

Tags: python, string, list, web-scraping, generator

Hi I am trying to get the first url of a google search based on queries in a list. For the sake of simplicity I am going to use the same code as a similar question 2 years prior.

```
from googlesearch import search

list_of_queries = ["Geeksforgeeks", "stackoverflow", "GitHub"]
results = []

for query in list_of_queries:
    results.append(search(query, tld="co.in", num=1, stop=1, pause=2))

print (results)
```

Now this returns a list of generator objects. A solution was found to print out the list of results by adding

```
for result in results:
    print (list(results))
```

However I want the results list to be in the form of a list of strings in order to web scrape the urls for data. One solution I found was to add

```
results_str = []
for result in results:
    results_str.append(list(result))
```

When I print results_str I get this as an output:

> [['https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/'], ['https://stackoverflow.com/'], ['https://github.com/']]

As one can see I cannot even use results_str directly as a list of urls to webscrape because of the additional brackets around each url. I thought I could work around it by removing the brackets by following this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8282553/removing-character-in-list-of-strings) and thus adding

```
results_str_new = [s.replace('[' and ']', '') for s in results_str]
```

But this simply results in an AttributeError

> AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'replace'

Either way even if I did get it to work it all seems unnecessarily unnecessary to do all this work just to convert a list of generator objects to strings to use as urls to webscrape so I was wondering if there were any alternatives. I know that one of my options is to use selenium but I don't really want to do that because I don't want the hassle of an instance of Chrome opening whenever I run my script.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting back a list of lists of string. To change that, you can use a list comprehension like this

```py
results_str = [url for result in results for url in result]
```

or you can change from `append` to `extend` if you don't want to go with a list comprehension. Extend just extends the list where es append inserts the lists into the list.

```py
results_str = []
for result in results:
    results_str.extend(result)
```

Comment: Perfect tysm!!!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you may be using a different version of googlesearch. I'm using googlesearch-python 1.1.0 so the call parameters are different. However, this should help:

```
from googlesearch import search

list_of_queries = ["Geeksforgeeks", "stackoverflow", "GitHub"]
results = []

for query in list_of_queries:
    results.extend([r for r in search(query, 1, 'en')])

print(results)
```

**Output:**

```
['https://www.youtube.com/c/GeeksforGeeksVideos/videos', 'https://stackoverflow.com/', 'https://stackoverflow.blog/', 'https://github.com/']
```

Which, as you can see, is a simple list of strings (URLs in this case)

Comment: Thanks mate. It works but I'm not sure why this module is so much slower. With this module my results take about a min to arrive